# Is $D = \{(x,y) \in R^2 ; x,y \geq 0 , x+y < 1 \}$ closed? Provide the closure of D.

Tags: general-topology

Let $D = \{(x,y) \in R^2:  x,y \geq 0 , x+y < 1 \}$.

I started with figuring out the boundary points which are

$$\delta D = 0 \times [0,1) \cup [0,1)\times 0 \cup   \{(x,y) \in R^2:  x,y \geq 0 , x+y = 1 \} $$

Then I recognized that $\{(x,y) \in R^2:  x,y \geq 0 , x+y = 1 \} $ $\notin$ $D$. Hence, I would have argued that $D$ is not closed.

The closure is $\overline{D} = D \cup \delta D = \{(x,y) \in R^2:  x,y \geq 0 , x+y \leq 1 \}$

Is this correct? Would appreciate any hints.

Edit: Definiton for a closed set: A set A is closed if it contains all its boundary points. That is if $x \in \delta A $ implies $x \in A $.

Comment: Intersection of two closed sets is closed.

Comment: In the title you say $\leq1$, but in the question you say $<1$. Which one is it?

Comment: A set is closed if it is the complement of an open set. Is $\overline{D}$ open?

Comment: Sorry the set given in the title was false. It is $x + y < 1 $

Comment: What exactly is your definition of open set in this question?

Comment: Added the definition above.

Comment: @HansHüttel I am not allowed to work with this since we have not defined closed sets like that.

Comment: How strange. That is the usual definition of closedness, but we cannot risk having you imprisoned. Are you allowed to use the fact that a set is closed if it contains all its limit points?

Comment: @HansHüttel Yeah this is what I tried above with $\delta D$.

Comment: Not as far as I can tell. $p$ is a limit point of $S$ if for every $\epsilon > 0$ we can find a $q \in S$ such that the distance $|| p - q || < \epsilon$.

Comment: @HansHüttel Ok i thought proceeding like this yields exactly the set of points I described above. However, I am generally struggling with finding boundary points.